# Semi Global handler removal

Tags: vb.net

I have a groupbox with checkboxes that I need to clear, but the checkbox.checkedchanged event fires (as it should), so i have to remone the relevant handlers. My code looks as though  it could be improved but every way I try gives errors. Is there a neater way to remove an add several event handlers at one shot?
     Private Sub resetAllControls(ByVal container As Control)

```
    RemoveHandler cbxFreq.CheckedChanged, AddressOf cbxFreq_CheckedChanged  ' May be  neater way to do this!!!
    RemoveHandler cbxCap.CheckedChanged, AddressOf cbxCap_CheckedChanged
    RemoveHandler cbxInd.CheckedChanged, AddressOf cbxInd_CheckedChanged
    RemoveHandler cbxImp.CheckedChanged, AddressOf cbxImp_CheckedChanged
    For Each ctrl As Control In container.Controls

        DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked = False
    Next
    AddHandler cbxFreq.CheckedChanged, AddressOf cbxFreq_CheckedChanged
    AddHandler cbxCap.CheckedChanged, AddressOf cbxCap_CheckedChanged
    AddHandler cbxInd.CheckedChanged, AddressOf cbxInd_CheckedChanged
    AddHandler cbxImp.CheckedChanged, AddressOf cbxImp_CheckedChanged
End Sub
 For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is Forms.TextBox Or TypeOf ctrl Is Forms.Label Then
            ctrl.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
```

I tried to elaborate on the DirectCast method and some variation of the last section that I used to hide the labels on the main form but this does not appear to work with the removehandler method. Is there a way?

It would be hard work if there were, say, 20 checkboxes to alter the state of.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: An other option is to have some flag "ignoreCheckEvent" and exit the sub when it is set to true. Also, ask yourself why you need to set the checkbox value without executing any of the logic inside the CheckedChanged. Maybe there's something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for that. Basically the user checks one of four Checkboxes which is in a groupbox container, then a textbox opens in the main form. The user then enters data there, returns to the groupbox, checks another check box to allow a second textbox to open. The program then calculates values from the two entries. I have a clear button that hides all the textboxes, clears the calculated and entered values and resets the checkboxes to unchecked, which fires the even unless the handler is removed. I will look at disabling the checkbox in its first checked handler.

Comment: Found this way to do it. Looks neater. Also disabled checked boxes as they were serviced.                                                                                                                                  Private Sub resetAllControls(ByVal container As Control)
        For Each ctrl As Control In container.Controls
            DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).Enabled = False
            DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked = False
            DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).Enabled = True
        Next
    End Sub